# Can I use an OpenGL compute shader to resolve a multisample texture?

Tags: opengl, shader, texture-mapping, render-to-texture, multisampling

My app renders a first scene into a texture bound to an FBO, then a compute shader does some processing on the texture image and writes it to another texture, which I then use for rendering a second scene.  All fine.

Now I'd like the first scene to be anti-aliased, so I create a multisample texture and bind it to the FBO before rendering. In the compute shader, I use `imageLoad(buf, pos, sample)` to read from an `image2DMS` (rather than `imageLoad(buf, pos)` from an `image2D`) to read all the samples and compute an average for the fragment, but it looks like all the samples have the same value.

Before I pull out the relevant bits of code and put them together into a simple test program, I'd like to know if I'm understanding the multi-sample model, and if what I'm trying to do is even possible.  I've been running on an nVidia GTX 660 with OpenGL 4.3 in Windows 7, driver 9.18.13.4052, July 2014.

Comment: Hi, please use quote marks for code: \`code\`

Comment: @ArnonZilca, you can always edit questions that have text formatting problems ;)

Comment: Yea, but then i'd miss on the educational value. ;) I was reviewing this q.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look up the difference between multisampling (MSAA) and super sampling (SSAA).

Multisampling uses a mutlisampled depth and color target. When your geometry primitive is rasterized, it is checked against all your samples determining its coverage. Afterwards the fragment shader is invoked only once per pixel and the result is copied to every covered sample. So you have only one fragment shader instance running where your primitive covers all samples inside the pixel. On the other hand when the primitive only covers a fraction of a pixel, only for that sample the fragment shaders color is copied. So you are able to collect n-sample different colors in one pixel, only when the primitives covers their certain sample in that pixel.

Super sampling is much easier to understand and needs much more computing power. Super sampling invokes for every sample one fragment shader instance. So you get different colors even if the same primitive covers all samples in the same pixel.

In OpenGL you are able to seamlessly move from MSAA to SSAA with the glMinSampleShading option. This setting describes how many fragment shader instances have to be executed at least per pixel. The value is a factor (0.0-1.0) to your number of samples. So if you choose a factor of 1.0 you will get super sampling.

Due to the point that MSAA only involves additional fragment shading instances based on different primitives, it can bee seen as a pure geometry based AA. So for example aliasing based on alpha textures is not resolved. That is the point why some sites calls the glMinSampleShading option also transparency samples for MSAA.

I recommend this nicely described and illustrated AA overview for further reading:
https://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/msaa-overview/